Length of an array conditional by date is returning the same in every scenario when running Test
First of all, here is the app code in question
Here are the variables in question
    const availability = [
        ['11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 PM', '12:30 PM', '1:00 PM', '1:30 PM', '2:00 PM', '2:30 PM', '3:00 PM', '3:30 PM', '4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '5:00 PM', "5:30 PM", '6:00 PM', '6:30 PM', '7:00 PM', '7:30 PM', '8:00 PM'],
        ['11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 PM', '12:30 PM', '1:00 PM', '1:30 PM', '2:00 PM', '2:30 PM', '4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '5:00 PM', "5:30 PM", '6:00 PM', '7:30 PM', '8:00 PM'],
        ['11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 PM', '12:30 PM', '2:30 PM', '3:00 PM', '3:30 PM', '4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '5:00 PM', "5:30 PM", '6:00 PM', '6:30 PM'],
        ['11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 PM', '1:00 PM', '1:30 PM', '2:00 PM', '2:30 PM', '3:00 PM', '3:30 PM', '4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '5:00 PM', '6:30 PM', '7:00 PM', '7:30 PM', '8:00 PM'],
        ['1:00 PM', '1:30 PM', '2:00 PM', '2:30 PM', '3:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '5:00 PM', "5:30 PM", '7:00 PM', '7:30 PM', '8:00 PM'],
        ['11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 PM', '12:30 PM', '1:00 PM', '2:30 PM', '3:00 PM', '3:30 PM', '4:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '6:00 PM', '6:30 PM', '7:00 PM', '7:30 PM', '8:00 PM'],
        ['4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '5:00 PM', "5:30 PM", '6:00 PM']
    ];

    const dayOfWeek = new Date(formik.values.date).getDay();
    const availabilityForDay = availability[dayOfWeek];


The date comes from a React DatePicker component.
Below is the code for the select element that's options change depending on the date selected. These two chunks are part of a form utilizing the useFormik hook


 <div className="dropdown time">
                        <label htmlFor='time'>Time</label>
                        <select
                            id='time'
                            name='time'
                            type="button"
                            className={formik.touched.time && formik.errors.time ? 'btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle error' : "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"}
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            value={formik.values.time}
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            required
                        >
                            <option value='Select Time'>Select Time</option>
                            {availabilityForDay.map((time, index) => <option data-testid='time-option' className="dropdown-item" value={time} key={index}>{time}</option>)}
                        </select>
                    </div>



My problem is that when I test the length of the availability array depending on a selected day, no matter which date I plug in, Jest is returning the length of the array for TODAY's date instead. The feature works when I interact with the page itself, but I am hoping someone can help me get the test to match that fact. The test I wrote is below:
test('time options are updating depending on the date selected', () => {
    render(<BookingForm />);

    const dateInput = screen.getByLabelText('Date');
    const timeSelection = screen.getByText('Select Time');
    let availability = screen.getAllByTestId('time-option');

    fireEvent.focus(dateInput, { target: { value: '09/30/2024' } });

    expect(dateInput).toHaveValue('09/30/2024');
    expect(timeSelection).toHaveValue('Select Time');
    expect(availability).toHaveLength(15);
});



We need to see the connection between screen.getAllByTestId('time-option') in your test and the code you posted. Is it ok that you're getting time-option before firing the event? Does fireEvent.focus fill out a form?

Thanks Schwern! I have updated the original post to include that information

You're using formik.values.date in your app, but I see it no where else; everywhere else seems to be time. I'd suggest adding some debug logging to your app code to see what is being received. Note: I don't know React, I'm applying general debugging principles.

Thanks Schwern, I appreciate your help. The rest of the formik.values.date data was not relevant to this particular issue, so I did not include it. There is a formik.values object that includes each of the fields within the form, but again, Thanks for taking a look and offering assistance!

Problem number one: I called fireEvent.focus, which surprisingly updated the value in the test, but does not function that way in the application itself, so I changed it to fireEvent.change.
Problem number two: I was using react-datepicker, which utilizes a pop up and ignores onChange, so the state was not being updated in the test.
To resolve. I kept react-datepicker, but applied the aria-hidden attribute, and created a second input element in the same div with className='visually-hidden' which provides both the state to be used for the test and increased accessibility! Double win!
Hope this saves some time for someone else!
